Question closed because it is not about programming
My question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79228149/, was closed as "not about development":

I explicitly mentioned that before the update the program I have been working on worked fine inside MSVC. And now it does not. Why doesn't that count as a software development question?

The question does not actually say anything about development of some software, and it is very vague in details, how can you expect anyone to answer if there are no detail about your code? This does indeed look like a question not about programming, a end user could have the same question as you wrote.

I am not an expert with Microsoft Visual C++, and your question may be programming-related, but from where I sit, it is missing too much information to be answerable or to be able to tell 100% that it isn't a non-programming OS issue. Your question could use a lot more information, and you may be asking it too soon in your debugging / solving process. Does your program do any debug logging? If not, why not? If so, what do the logs tell you?

I think that was a rather poor choice of close reason. It very well could be programming related, we just can't know because the question is completely lacking in details.

What kind of details you are looking for? I did say I'm trying to run the program from inside MSVC, right? I did say that I'm going to continue writing the code but will not be able to validate it, right? What else are you looking for?

Ja. Screams Close vote for "Needs details or clarity" to me. All we can do with what's given is leave "Brother, I feel your pain" comments.


You don't indicate which update you installed 2. The error isn't programming related.  The application is just crashing. 3. There are hundreds of reasons for "The application was unable to start correctly. Click OK to close the application." 4. You provided 0 code. So, I wouldn't be able to reproduce the error if I wanted to investigate.


Does the program run outside MSVC or does it fail with a similar error?

By MSVC you mean Visual Studio? If so what version? What compiler version is your project configured to use? You asked for what information should have been included.

@SecurityHound, i don't know what was installed.2. It's not just crashing - I gave the reaso for the crash. 4. What code? It's not executing single line of code. It's crashing somewhere in ntdll... and as much as I'd love to - im not working for MS to get a backtrace.

@user4581301, fails with same error.

@SecurityHound, i thought that programming community has to know that specific acronym.  Guess not. Yes it Visual Studio. The version is 2017.  Not sure about the compiler - just use MSVC solution.

We don't work for Microsoft either so we can't tell you why an update broke your code either. Much less when you don't know what update got installed.

I recommend adding that information to the question. Also grab the return code. I can't prove anything, but if you look the code up, it'll probably tell you there's a DLL or other resource missing.

And folks, remember that delete is not a super closevote. Give the guy a chance to fix the question.

The Question has in the meantime been deleted (not by the OP), => could a Screenshot be added to this Question for <10k-Users...? // Also there is a typo in the Title, and mentioning indeed (in the Qt) what 'MSVC' means would be handy, this is 'Meta', we are not all knowledgeable in the same technical areas...

"It's not just crashing - I gave the reaso for the crash. 4. What code? It's not executing single line of code. It's crashing somewhere in ntdll" - I don't understand the claim. Nothing in your question says anything about ntdll. Nor is it clear why anything should need to run from another dll before your program's code. If your program works from the command line, then the next logical step is to see if you can write a new "hello world" program in MSVC and run it from there. (If the problem is with MSVC getting broken by an update, that's probably a bug report for Microsoft instead.)

@Igor - I am only familiar with MSVC, but when I am running a program in VS, I say VS not MSVC. Technically, I also say MSVC++. Which MSVC compiler you are using is important information. I can also use Visual Studio Code to program in MSVC++

Yeah..., pretty "low quality" Question for me... If that Qt had gone through the 'Staging Ground', it would never had been published as is, I would have asked the User to take the [tour] (yep, still to do!) and to read the [ask] page, and then nearly all Canned Comments from the 'SG' apply: Title vague en non-descriptive (with a typo also, "Wndows" [sic]), missing details (Config Info with all versions for OS + MSVC) and basic troubleshooting to identify the "faulty" KB-WinUpdate, Code as [mre] and Log missing), the '[update]' Tag has little use. [A bit surprising for a User with 500 Qt's.]

It should also be mentioned that this pattern of making low quality questions is not productive, as eventually you will get a question ban, which is automatic and not negotiable.

We still don't have enough information to help you, but this is almost certainly a third party DLL that's failing.  I'd really suggest you run sxstrace to debug the issue.

@chivracq, I'm sorry - whats Qt? I know only one Qt thing..

@AnonCoward, its almost certainly is. Problem is - even f I find out which one I still have no idea how to fix it.....

@Igor Qt is short for "question".

Is it? I was thinking Quicktime or the the Qt framework

@WeijunZhou, I;m curious - in what universe Qt means question, Especially when it started with the capital Q...

Yeah, "Qt" = Question indeed, I usually type "Question (Qt)" the 1st time I use that word in a Comment but I was fighting the 600-Char Limit for Comments and had to shorten my Comment to stay below 600 Chars. And I thought "QT" for "Question" was pretty obvious with context, [Question low-quality] + [what get published in the 'Staging Ground'? => Questions.] + [User with (nearly) 500 Qt's => 500 Questions]. // Only 'Meta' Users on 'SO' seem to have difficulties with this abbreviation while the whole Site is only about "Questions", I've used it 1000's times and never had sbd asking before...

@chivracq, please check user4591301 comment. You need to be extra careful when talking to developers/engineers with abbreviation like this...

@Igor , yeah-yeah, I know. Again, I thought the context was making this abbreviation obvious, and I was fighting the 600-Char Limit. // Talking about "abbreviations", what does the "t" mean in your Title then...? I mentioned that typo 7 hours ago already, but it still hasn't been corrected...

Was this program written on the computer where it crashed or was it migrated to?Have you checked the dependencies? What OS version did you write the code and what OS version did it crash on? Have you tried running it in compatibility mode? Which VS version of did you write the code for and which VS version of did it crash? If they are different, did you do an automated update of the project or did you just run it? Have you tried run in debug mode? What was the result? These are missing information that at last would help us understand your problem, but they still wouldn't open the post.

@AugustoVasques, program is written on this same machine with this same MSVC 2017 IDE. it is being compiled and run in Debug mode as it is not finished. The laptop is running Windows 8.1. Program is written in C++. No dependencies other than wxwidgets and OS.

@Igor- All this information you are sharing in a comment here should have been originally provided.

Huh? Windows 8.1? That's out of support for nearly 2 years now, and has no ESU program as far as I'm aware. You shouldn't receive Windows updates on that. The original question should've both contained that and a lot more clarification on what's going on, for example, which updates did you install and how did you install them?

@Igor? This is not a discussion for META. As already said, this kind of information should have been included with the question on main site.

@ErikA, question updated with that info

@ErikA - The author didn't receive updates, or they didn't receive new updates, they simply installed 2 year old updates recently. The whole update is a red herring anyways.

To make sure I understand the situation:

You are a programmer.

You wrote a program.

It used to work on your computer.

Then you used Windows Update and updated Windows.

Now the program doesn't work any more.


Therefore, we can - only if you have made every proper debugging effort and ruled out other causes (i.e.: anything else that changes on your computer beside the update, e.g. moving your program to a different directory and messing up some relative paths; or corrupting a config file that your program cares about; or...) - conclude: the update to Windows changed something on the computer, which made the program stop working.
There are two possible questions you could be asking now - and you must choose one:

"What was changed by the update, that made my program stop working?" - this is clearly not about programming. Everyone who uses Windows (almost all of them not programmers) has to worry about Windows Update, and sometimes it breaks programs. Writing the program yourself does not make it special. The update changed whatever it changed, and it simply doesn't care about your program. The question is best answered by the documentation (KB articles) for the update itself. If you must use the Stack Exchange network, please try Super User instead.

"Why did these changes make the program stop working?" Okay, now you have a possible debugging question. But the question is still nowhere near meeting standards. We don't do the debugging for you here; it is your responsibility to:

Figure out which change caused the problem;
Investigate how your program interacts with that change - for example, by checking your program's logs (and making it do more detailed logging), using a debugger etc.;
Clearly explain what goes wrong - a mess like The application was unable to start correctly. Click OK to close the application doesn't tell us anything useful (you didn't even explain whether this comes from your program itself, or from MSVC!); and finally
Create a minimal reproducible example of only the part of the code that is directly relevant to the problem, but making sure it is self contained and can thus directly demonstrate the problem (with suitable Windows updates applied) without adding or changing anything.




Aside from this, please read [ask] and pay attention to what you write on Stack Overflow. A typo in the title will never make a good impression. And you have properly asked about closed questions on Meta before, and have been around for over 13 years, so you should know not to use the main site to post these objections.

About debugging and isolating the problem: you should also try to locate the .exe that MSVC created and directly run it from a CMD window. Then you will directly see your programs stderr and stdout, and should be able to rule out any MSVC misconfiguration problem.

You also have almost 500 questions on the main site now, so you should very well understand by now that things like "ALL, ... I really need help to continue work. TIA!!" do not belong in questions.

It's also worth adding that both this question and the one you linked in your first comment were posted on Meta.SE first and migrated here. The author's been around for a while, and has made many posts here, so I don't understand why they'd post on the wrong meta all of a sudden. I guess they were hoping that posting there would be an "escalation" from posting here since the global meta has powers over other sites, but that's not the case.

@gparyani - The author has a clear pattern. They ask a vague question then ask why the question is closed. This latest example is just one in a very long pattern. The author has gotten feedback and is simply arguing that the missing information isn’t required or should already be known (for some reason). They haven’t added any additional information, likely due to the fact, the question was deleted because it wasn’t being improved. I can’t explain the situation the author finds themselves in.

@KarlKnechtel, as a software developer those 2 things were exactly what I asked.. And guess what - 1. Absolutely nothing changed. Only the updates were installed. Moreover - the updates were pushed were not for MSVC itself but for something else.. 2 I just updated the question. As you  can see the update is for .NET which is nowhere near C++ Redistributable MSVC complains about.

@gparyani Ah, I see; the migration banner is removed when a closure banner is added....

"as a software developer those 2 things were exactly what I asked" - you must choose one and one only for a Stack Overflow question.

@KarlKnechtel The migration banner is removed 60 days after migration, as after that time it was deemed no longer necessary to continue highlighting the fact that it was migrated at the very top of the post.

@KarlKnechtel, why? They are related.

A typo in the title? It is present in this very meta question as well. If the author cannot show that he cares enough about it, why should we?

@WeijunZhou, when half of the keyboard works on the 3rd or 4th attempt - I will also pass you questions...

@Igor you still did not bother to correct it, even when pointed out, if your keyboard is broken and bothers you, replace it, I don't see how that is anything we should be bothered with if you don't care enough.

@Igor - You do understand that Microsoft Visual C++ is directly connected to .NET Framework?
